# Script sometimes stuck at arcpy.SplitRaster_management

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool

my problem is that my script sometimes stuck then it use `arcpy.SplitRaster_management`.

```
import arcpy
import os 

#nearly 700 rows of script

fclist: [ ...] # some fc
rasterlist = [...] # many raster
for raster in rasterlist:
    rasterpro = arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(raster, "in_memory\\rasterpro", 25832)
    for fc in fclist:
        os.makedirs(newfolder + "\\" + filenamenew + "_" + os.path.basename(fc))
        arcpy.SplitRaster_management(rasterpro,
                                    newfolder + "\\" + filenamenew + "_" + os.path.basename(fc), # it is a correct path, which should work fine
                                    filenamenew + "_" + os.path.basename(fc) + "_",
                                    "POLYGON_FEATURES",
                                    "#",
                                    "NEAREST",
                                    "#",
                                    "#",
                                    "#",
                                    "#",
                                    "#",
                                    "#",
                                    fc)

# some more rows of script
```

Most of the times it works just fine, but sometimes the script just stops there and doesn´t go on. If i restart the script, sometimes it works without problems, then sometimes the first itteration does not work. So the problem does not occur after a set number of itteration, the same Feature Class or with the same raster!

Did i do something wrong with my inputs in `arcpy.SplitRaster_management`?

EDIT: If i run the script inside my Editor (Pyzo), the problem does not occur. Only if i use it inside a Toolbox in ArcGIS Pro.

EDIT2: I wrote a second shorter script, to look if i can repeat the error. I used other FC and other raster.

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
path = r"D:\Projekt"

FC1 = path + r"\tool_und_gdb\polyfc.gdb\polyfc1"
FC2 = path + r"\tool_und_gdb\polyfc.gdb\polyfc2"
FC3 = path + r"\tool_und_gdb\polyfc.gdb\polyfc3"
fclist = [FC2, FC2, FC3]
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\Projekt\raster.gdb"
list = arcpy.ListRasters()
x = 1
for raster in list:
    for fc in fclist:
        name = os.path.basename(raster) + "_" + os.path.basename(fc) + "_"
        arcpy.AddMessage(name)
        arcpy.SplitRaster_management(raster,
                                    r"D:\Users\Jakobsm\Desktop\test",
                                    name,
                                    "POLYGON_FEATURES",
                                    "#",
                                    "NEAREST",
                                    "#",
                                    "#",
                                    "#",
                                    "#",
                                    "#",
                                    "#",
                                    fc)
        arcpy.AddMessage(x)
        x +=1
```

The same error happens, if i use the script inside of a Toolbox in ArcGIS Pro, but not if i run the script inside of my Python Editor.

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problems but you should use os.path.join to combine paths instead of things like this: `newfolder + "\\" + filenamenew + "_" + os.path.basename(fc))`

Comment: Are the rasters being sourced locally on your computer or from a network directory?

Comment: They are local.

Comment: Perhaps you can add multiple print statements between lines to see which line actually hangs; you could also execute repair geometry https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/repair-geometry.htm on your feature class prior to os.makedirs just in case it's a dodgy geometry gumming up the works. When you find out what line is hanging please edit your question to highlight where the hanging is occurring, thanks.

Comment: That i did already before i posted the question. Because of that i know arcpy.SplitRaster_management is the problem and there it  stuck (if i put prints before and after it, the first is printed but not the second!). I have tested repair geometry but it does not help.